# Swagger Documentation in jersey related framework swagger.json url needs authentication 401

Tags: javascript, java, swagger, jersey

I am trying to implement swagger in my project. it works fine in recent days I implemented a token to authenticate the API. After implementing the authorization when the swagger URL is loaded http://localhost:8080/bms2-api/swagger/ it loads UI and gives the message on the screen as **401: {"msg": "token not found", "msgs":{"*": "token not found"}, "unauthorized": false} http://localhost:8080/bms2-api/api/swagger.json** I don't know how to pass the token in the header for swagger.json URL. Screen capture are given below
[image]

Comment: You have to skip the `swagger.json` path in the Interceptor to get the proper response.

Comment: Yes, made it same way you suggested